Not able to assign value into objectbox model with relation in flutter
I have model class which is created using Json to dart conversion. When I use this class as objectbox model, I can't set the relation. If I set the relation then jsonTo, jsonFrom methods not working properly.
    ***@Entity()
class ShipmentDetail {
  @Id()
  int id = 0;
  late String barcode;
  
  //late Area? area;
  late ShipmentType? shipmentType;
  late List<ShipmentAction>? shipmentActions;
  late bool isSynced = false;
  late String startDeliveryTime = "00:00:00";
  late String endDeliveryTime = "00:00:00";
  late bool isChange = false;
  late String civilId;
  late String? latitude;
  late String? longitude;
  final area = ToOne<Area>();
  @Backlink('ShipmentAction')
  final objshipmentActions = ToMany<ShipmentAction>;
  //
  // String endDeliveryTime = "00:00:00";
  ShipmentDetail({
    required this.barcode,
    
    // this.area,
    this.shipmentType,
    //this.shipmentActions,
    this.isSynced = false,
    required this.civilId,
    required this.latitude,
    required this.longitude,
  });
  ShipmentDetail.init();
  ShipmentDetail.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    barcode = json['barcode'];
    
    civilId = json['civilId'] ?? '';
    longitude = json['longitude'] ?? '';
    latitude = json['latitude'] ?? '';
    area.target = (json['area'] != null ? Area.fromJson(json['area']) : null);
    //area = json['area'] != null ? new Area.fromJson(json['area']) : null;
    shipmentType = json['shipmentType'] != null
        ? ShipmentType.fromJson(json['shipmentType'])
        : null;
    if (json['shipmentActions'] != null) {
      shipmentActions =[] ;
      json['shipmentActions'].forEach((v) {
        shipmentActions?.add(ShipmentAction.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['barcode'] = barcode;
   
    data['area'] = area.target?.toJson();
      if (shipmentType != null) {
      data['shipmentType'] = shipmentType?.toJson();
    }
    if (shipmentActions != null) {
      data['shipmentActions'] =
          shipmentActions?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
// if (objshipmentActions != null) {
//       data['shipmentActions'] =
//           objshipmentActions.   .map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
//     }
    return data;
  }
}***

   
   ***@Entity()
class Area {
  @Id()
  int? id = 0;
  late String? description;
  late String? descriptionEn;
  late int? paciId;
  Area(
      {required this.id,
      required this.description,
      this.descriptionEn = "",
      required this.paciId});
  Area.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    description = json['description'] ?? '';
    descriptionEn = json['descriptionEn'] ?? "";
    paciId = json['paciId'] ?? 0;
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = id;
    data['description'] = description;
    data['descriptionEn'] = descriptionEn;
    data['paciId'] = paciId;
    return data;
  }
}
    @Entity()
class ShipmentAction {
  @Id()
  int id = 0;

  late int? newBulkId;

  

  late String? description;
  // Null newBulkTbln;

  late ActionType? actions;

  final shipmentDetails = ToOne<ShipmentDetail>();

  ShipmentAction(
      {required this.id,
      required this.newBulkId,
      
      required this.description,
      // this.newBulkTbln,
      this.actions});

  ShipmentAction.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    newBulkId = json['newBulkId'];
    
    actions = json['actions'] != null
        ? ActionType.fromJson(json['actions'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['newBulkId'] = newBulkId;
    data['id'] = id;
    d
    // data['newBulkTbln'] = this.newBulkTbln;
    if (actions != null) {
      data['actions'] = actions?.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}


how to make the relation to the area and shipment action classes from shipmentdetails with jsonfrom and jsonto methods
In below code whenever i am adding the data from list, the ship object having the values inside for loop without any issue but after save(put) the data(area details). it does not exist in below get list.
**late objBox.Box<ReturnReason> _storageReason;

  //Constructor
  ShipmentDbService() {
       _storageReason = objectbox.store.box<ReturnReason>();
  }


  Result<List<ShipmentDetail>> addAll(List<ShipmentDetail> data) {
    
    try {
      

      for (var item in data) {
        // _storageShipment.objshipmentActions.put(item);

        final ship = ShipmentDetail.normal();
        ship.area.target = item.area.target;
    //other properties

    _storageShipment.put(ship);

        }

   var shipmentsLst = _storageShipment.getAll().toList();**


Can you help edit your answer? Mainly what do you mean by not working properly? and what would be the expected result with minimal code reproduction/exacmple? This would really help clear things a lot.

Hi @IcyHerrscher, Actually I want to assign value to area model inside shipmentdetails class, but I can't able to assign values to area (relation model) with this structured class. Another thing is if I can assign the values, then not able to pass the assigned value into json using to jsonto method.

Can you make it clearer by showing us the section of the codes that you are unable to assign/reassign? And also the part where you can't assign value into json as well.

@IcyHerrscher In below code whenever I am adding the data from list, the ship object having the values inside for loop without any issue but after save (put) the data (area details). It does not exist in below get list.
Result<List> addAll(List data) {
for (var item in data) {
final ship = ShipmentDetail.normal();
ship.area.target = item.area.target;
_storageShipment.put(ship);       }
var shipmentsLst = _storageShipment.getAll().toList();

Please Edit your question with the code. I don't mean it as adding it in a comment. Edit your question and add that particular code in it, thank you.
Also how did you create that data? From an API? if so, please add that code to the question as well.

I can't really pin-point what the exact issue is, but maybe reading the docs will help you understand: https://docs.objectbox.io/relations
